# SSL Cert Error in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, networking

We followed the guide to setup an SSL application gateway - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-ssl-portal.

When I create the rule for https traffic, I get an error:

> Failed to save configuration changes to application gateway
>   'xxxgateway'. Error: Data must be specified for Certificate
>   /subscriptions/Subscription_ID/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/xxxgateway/sslCertificates/xx_cert.

Can someone let me know what might be causing this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I encountered the same issue. I reached out to MS support and they suggested to remove the configuration directly from the Resource Manager code https://resources.azure.com/.

Answer (score 14):

I recently ran into this error and found that my application gateway hadn't finished updating after adding the https listener. After that completed, I was able to add rules.

Comment: Encountered the same issue here. It took upwards of 25 minutes to finally complete.

Comment: I had to delete existing AG and recreate from scratch. Had to wait to complete each update process before making the next.

Answer (score 6):

Open the following link to have a look at the details of your Application Gateway:

```
https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/{applicationGatewayName}
```

There is an *sslCertificates* array with the certificates the Gateway can use. You can check the provisioning state of the certificate and the actual ID of the certificate to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Adrian,
I have tested and confirmed that updating an SSL certificate for offload works fine. The error is stating that when doing the put for creating the certificate with the API that there is no data.  This could be caused by a bad password for the certificate. I would recommend re-exporting the private key for your certificate and try to upload it again.

Answer (score 0):

> https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/{applicationGatewayName}

If you navigate to your Application gateway, you should see the Data under Authentication certificate.

Sample:

"authenticationCertificates": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/Application-gateway-demo/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/AppGWDemo/authenticationCertificates/test",
        "etag": "W/\"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"",
        "properties": {
          "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
          "data": "LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tDQpNSUlEQWpDQ0FlNmdBd0lCQWdJUTZkTjhtOUhaWDZKRUlyMi9Nak5BaURBSkJnVXJEZ01DSFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/authenticationCertificates"
      }

If not, then click on Edit and add your authentication certificate over here. (Open your .cer cert in Wordpad and copy past the entire string over there and do a PUT operation)